# How to force Npgsql to use CommandTimeout value from connection string in ASP.NET MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, npgsql

ASP.NET MVC3 application uses npgsql 2.0.12.0 to get data in Mono with mod_mono.
Sometimes timeout exceptions below occur. Request duration is 31 seconds if exception occurs.

CommandTimeout in connection string is set to 5 minutes using

```
        NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            CommandTimeout = 5*60,  // 5 min
            Host = Config.Server,
            Database = Config.DefaultDataBase,
            UserName = Config.ServerUser,
            Port = Config.Port,
            SslMode = SslMode.Prefer,
            SSL = true,
        };
```

How to force npgsql use use timeout 5 minutes and not to throw excpetion after 31 seconds ?
In postgresql.con file statement_timeout is not set so it looke like this is not coming from server.

Query is executed using ExecuteReader:

```
        using (IDbConnection conn = DataAccessBase.CreateConnection())
        using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(command, paramNames);
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    string[] names = new string[reader.FieldCount];
                    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                    {
                        names[i] = reader.GetName(i);
                    }
                    Func<IDataRecord, MyDataContext, T> objInit = InitializerCache<T>.GetInitializer(names, ConvertValue != null);
                    do
                    { // walk the data 
                        yield return objInit(reader, this);
                    } while (reader.Read());
                }
                while (reader.NextResult()) { } // ensure any trailing errors caught 
            }
        }
```

Exception occurs after 31 seconds from start of request.

Request header:

```
Connection  Keep-alive
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
From    googlebot(at)googlebot.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

Exception:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException:
A timeout has occured. If you were establishing a connection, increase Timeout value in ConnectionString. If you were executing a command, increase the CommandTimeout value in ConnectionString or in your NpgsqlCommand object.
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.ProcessBackendResponsesEnum (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadyState.QueryEnum (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector context, Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand command) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.QueryEnum (Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand queryCommand) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader (CommandBehavior cb) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior cb) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Can you try setting the command timeout where you call the ExecuteReader()? If it works, it will confirm there is a problem passing the commandtimeout from connectionstring down to NpgsqlCommand objects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20265827/198048 is this an NpgSQL Bug?

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, but I think that your CommandTime is incorrect:

`CommandTimeout = 5*60,  // 5 min`

It is 30 seconds (300 milliseconds).

Comment: npgsql source code and docs contain `The time (in seconds) to wait for the command to execute` Also unit test TimeoutFirstParameters() sets value to 1 and calls pg_sleep(1.5) and verifies that Timeout exception occurs. So this is in seconds. Why do you think that this is in milliseconds ?

Comment: I was wrong, it is time in seconds really. I have clarified in the documentation.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, 300 ms is not 30 seconds. it's 0.3 seconds. There are 1000 milliseconds in a second.