# postgresql no responding suddenly

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have written a program about getting data from postgresql by c#. I have run the program for a monthly and it run perfect. However, it suddenly cannot work today.

Here is the SQL code I use:

```
    select count(call_id) , dt,hr,mn from ( select i.call_id,a.dt,hr,mn from 
   (SELECT call_id ,to_char("event_Time" ,'yyyy-MM-dd') as dt, to_char(extract(hour 
   from "event_Time"),'FM00') as hr ,to_char(floor(extract(minute from 
   "event_Time")/30)*30,'FM00') as mn from ivr_event  where "event_Time" between 
   '2014-2-11 00:00:00' and '2014-2-11 23:59:59'  and status='playGreeting' and 
   stage='InqiryMenu'  group by dt,hr,mn,call_id) a,ivr_event i where a.call_id = 
   i.call_id  and status='getDigits'  and stage='Language' and click ='3' and 
   "event_Time" between '2014-2-11 00:00:00' and '2014-2-11 23:59:59' group by
   i.call_id,dt,hr,mn ) result group by dt,hr,mn order by dt,hr,mn
```

Here is the C# code to select query and return an arraylist

```
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                String connstring = "Server=" + dataSource
                + ";Port=" + port + ";" + "User Id=" + userID
                + ";Password=" + password + ";Database=" + databaseName + 
                ";CommandTimeout=0;";


                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);

                conn.Open();

                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, conn);


                ds.Reset();
                // filling DataSet with result from NpgsqlDataAdapter
                da.Fill(ds);
                // since it C# DataSet can handle multiple tables, we will select first
                dt = ds.Tables[0];

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    temp = "";
                    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        temp += item + ";";
                    }

                    if (row.ItemArray.Length >= 1)
                        temp = temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 1);

                    result.Add(temp);
                }

                conn.Close();
```

The program is getting the multiple counts with different WHERE clause within 1 hour by only 1 SQL.
Then, I loop for 24 times to get the whole day counts.

It is okay for almost a month. However, when I use the same program without changing anything today, it seems always waiting the result by nothing I get. I only can end the process by stop the postgresql services(I have set no timeout).

And we got the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance.
```

A very strange case is when I choose an very old data, it is okay. When I choose last week data, it failed. However, I have use the same sql a few days ago and it worked!

Any suggestions for me? Thank you very much!

P.S. sorry that the sql is updated. here is the real SQL that can be run

Comment: is `result` null? Or is there some data in the db that is acidently being populated with null?

Comment: It may be that the planner switches to a different, bad plan on recent dates. To test this, compare the results of `EXPLAIN` of the query that runs fine against the one that never finishes.

Comment: Your SQL code is full of syntax errors. If you want help post something real and legible.

Comment: No, that isn't the SQL you use, because it cannot possibly run. Show the real, unedited SQL. If that's actually an excerpt from some kind of SQL generator, show the resulting generated SQL - you can get it from the PostgreSQL log files by setting `log_statement = 'all'` and reloading PostgreSQL. Also, check `pg_stat_activity` to see whether the statement is just running for ages, or if there's something else going on. You might also want to check for a lock conflict; see wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: the program seems ok without changing anything or restart today! Then I try to stop the  postgresql service and the problem again! After that I find the log in postgresql, I got ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request & LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 
LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection. Then I found the following link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265827/why-does-a-query-time-out-when-it-is-within-its-timeout-limit). Here is my version:postgresql-9.1   npgsql :2.0.11.0